# Get DbContext's DbSet<T> where T is variable

Tags: c#, entity-framework, dbcontext, dbset

I have a DbContext looking somewhat like this:

```
class MyDbContext: DbContext
{
    public DbSet<Class1> Set1 {get;set;}
    public DbSet<Class2> Set2 {get;set;}
    ...
}
```

where Class1, Class2 ... : BaseClass
The thing is I'm reading data from xml and I use a dictionary that looks like this:

```
public class XmlNode
{
    public Func<BaseClass> CreateEntity { get; set; }
    ...
}

public static Dictionary<string, XmlNode> Nodes = new Dictionary<string, XmlNode>()
{
    ["Tag1"] = new XmlNode()
    {

        CreateEntity = () => new Class1(),
    }

    ...
}
```

And then I have to compare the read entity to an existing table and maybe add it. But I can't find a way to get the approptiate table without making a different function for every Class I have. Is there a way to get a DbSet where Class is a variable?

Comment: The only way a generic type parameter can be variable is in another generic method/type. You'd still have to call that method with a known type though. If you won't know the required type until run time, you need to use Reflection.

Comment: I tried using it and I can get the value of the DbSet property, but then I need to search it for matching records and maybe add a new one, but since GetValue returns object, I can't do that. Casting doesn't work because you can't cast (DbSet<BaseClass>) DbSet<Class1>

Comment: Once you start using Reflection, you have to keep using it, e.g. if you use Reflection to invoke a method that returns an object, you then have to use Reflection on that object to get property values, etc.

Answer (score 1):

The `DbContext` your data context derives from has a method called `Set(Type t)` that accepts a type, type can be created from string.

For the scenario you've described you can create a `DbSet` from the string in your XML by

```
var typeName = "Some.Namespace.AndType";
DbSet t = Set(Type.GetType(typeName));
```

Note that you can't use linq or lambda expressions to query the resulting object, unless you cast it to a typed `DbSet<T>` or use a library like `System.Linq.Dynamic` which would allow you to call `t.AsQueryable().Where("SomeProperty == @value");`, but this should get you started.

Comment: I knew about the Set method, but didn't know how to make it queryable. Are there any downsides to using AsQueryable? If not, your solution works perfectly.

Comment: If it's helped, mark it as answer. Remember, since DbSet already implements IQueryable, this call enables converting your queries to expression trees and in your case SQL. https://weblogs.asp.net/zeeshanhirani/using-asqueryable-with-linq-to-objects-and-linq-to-sql

Answer (score 0):

From [how to check whether dbcontext sett exists in model](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10749307/how-to-check-whether-dbcontext-sett-exists-in-model)
you can just check if it exist then get DBset after checked

```
if(Exists<yourentity>())
{
   ... TEntity exist
}
```

from  link

```
public bool Exists<TEntity>() where TEntity : class
{
    string entityName = typeof(TEntity).Name;
    ObjectContext objContext = ((IObjectContextAdapter)this).ObjectContext;
    MetadataWorkspace workspace = objContext.MetadataWorkspace;
    return workspace.GetItems<EntityType>(DataSpace.CSpace).Any(e => e.Name == entityName);
}
```